# Add key, value at certain position by passing a position to the function to modify a yaml file

Tags: python, pyyaml

yaml file contents:

```
a: a1
b: 
  b1:
  - name: c1-name
    type:
      ctype:
        content: true
```

I can safe load the above contents using `pyyaml` module and modify the data (newkey to add, value) as follows

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)
data['b]['b1'][0]['type']['ctype'][newkey to add]=value
```

But I want to do this for some other yaml files where position to add the new key, values are different, so I decided to write this in a function by sending filepath, position and key, value as arguments as follows:

```
def modify_yaml(filepath,position,key,value):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        data = yaml.safe_load(f)
    data[position][key]=value
    return data
```

But the above code doesn't work. Please help if there is a way to achieve this.

```
"b": {
    "b1": [
      {
        "name": "c1-name",
        "type": {
          "ctype": {
            "content": true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: If your yaml-formatted files all have a similar layout and you might be able to devise a way to programmatically specify a position inside them that the function could use — otherwise I think creating such a generic `modify_yaml()` function would be very difficult if not impossible.

Comment: It doesnt work, because your code is incomplete. Especially it is gueswork about what your `position` looks like. Is that some line-number? Or something like `b.b1.0.type.ctype` or `b/b1/0/type/ctype` ?

Comment: @Anthon it is like ['b]['b1'][0]['type']['ctype']

Comment: @martineau Thank you, currently i just broke it down to two functions, one to read the data from yaml and return the json data, then i modify it and call the other to write to a file in yaml

Comment: @KumarMantri So I assume that is a string that is unique and predertined for every YAML file. You have to parse it, or if you are confident about the security of your input, just evaluate it. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Anthon  yes i will parse the string(which is the position where i want the change) and also the key , value at that position.  "security of the input, just evaluate it? " sorry i don't understand this part